# Error: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int in Information design tool?

Tags: business-objects

I'm joining two tables on columns having VARCHAR data type but getting below error.

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

I'm using SAP BO Information design tool 4.1

Please let me know if you have any idea on resolving this error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The join May not be the part that particular problem

Have you tried changing the data provider to fewer result columns, to see if the error persists or disappears ?

A 'syntax check' for the entire universe is probably not a bad idea :)